# How do I turn off the search box that appears when I press Alt in Ubuntu 11?

Tags: ubuntu

How do I turn off the search box that appears when I press Alt in Ubuntu 11? Older versions of Ubuntu don't have the behavior at all but I can't even find what it's called.

Comment: Dupe on AskUbuntu stack exchange site: [How do I modify or disable the HUD's use of the Alt key?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key)

Comment: Ubuntu 11 or Ubuntu 12? I think the HUD appears in Ubuntu 12.04 and not in earlier versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this helps but, You can change the hotkey for the HUD by going to System Settings --> Keyboard --> Short-cuts.

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work for me in my Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) installation.  "Key to show the HUD" is marked "Disabled" but that annoying search box keeps coming up - I use that key for other things!